# Dual Monitor Lock Screen Problem

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 12.04
Nvidia GTX 550-Ti
x-swat Nvidia driver

Problem:

Using 2 monitors. When screen locks there is a blue box on top of the wallpaper and password dialog box that hides the field for entering your password or switching users.

Problem is on 2 systems with similar hardware (Nvidia card, x-swat driver, dual monitors)

You can still type your password in blindly and hit enter to login but it's irritating to not be able to see the dialog box.

Comment: What 'blue box'? Is this something your monitor is doing separately from Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a blue area of the screen that is on top of both the wallpaper and the dialog box but only on the main monitor and only about 3/4 starting in the top left corner. If I move the mouse over where the password field should be, the mouse changes into a text cursor... I'll add a screenshot

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-slOE3M9ABEA/UGyt0TmoHlI/AAAAAAAADwU/QaqxfZjplzM/s800/photo.JPG

Comment: Very strange, that's definitely a bug. No idea why that's happening, sorry.

Comment: I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Comment: There is already [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1061787).

Comment: Upgrading the Nvidia drivers seems to have fixed this problem. I have exact same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia card. I updated to: "Nvidia binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)"

Comment: Correcting my own comment above. I still see this issue even after upgrading nvidia drivers.